# Can magnetism create kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy

If a magnet is accelerated in a solenoid using current, the magnet is gaining kinetic energy from the current. How?

If not, there will be no effect on solenoid current. Hence electrical energy will remain as it is. Does energy dissipated depend upon whether we place magnet or not?

Please guide me through it as I don't know much about electromagnetism.

Answer (score 1):

The story here is subtle.

The net effect is "the magnetic field itself contains energy".  The kinetic energy of the accelerated object ultimately comes from the charged object beginning to move, this current creating its own magnetic field, this field creating a back-flux to cancel the original magnetic field, and resulting in a net energy extraction from the initial magnetic field.

In the case of something like a solenoid, this will mean "the source of emf will have to draw more energy to maintain whatever current it is maintaining," which will ultimately be where the kinetic energy of the object comes from.

Comment: So, it's closer to "the work is being done *on* the magnetic field" than "the magnetic field is doing work"